# How to find URLs in text and make links?

Tags: php

I'm using this code to find URLs in text and make links:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/((((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/)|www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\/\S*)?)/";
$text = preg_replace( $reg_exUrl, "<a href=\"$1\" target='_blank'>$1</a>", $text);
```

but it won't make link if website doesn't have http,https,ftp,ftps or www, for example, google.com won't become a link.
Also, if website only have www, for example, www.google.com, link is mywebsite.com/www.google.com.
Can you help me with these problems, that if there is somewebsite.com and www.somewebsite.com in text, it will become normal link?

Answer (score 0):

Assumming your original Regexp is correct, all you need to do is:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/((((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/)|www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\/\S*)?)/";
                                                     ^ -- Optional!
```

There's a major problem that you will have to tackle here. Suppose the text contains "google.com", your Regex will spit out `<a href="google.com">google.com</a>` which would give you a 404 (because that will lead you to yourDomain.com/google.com)! You will need to prepend `http://` (or other protocols). Look into the captures.All you need to do is find if this exists, or else prepend a default one.